# LaTeX Box plot drawing using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot

Two issues I have in the following code. I want to put the box in the middle of the line and I like to show the for the maximum value. Any suggestion will be appreciate. Thanks.

```
  \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{pgf,pgfplots}

    \usetikzlibrary{fit,calc}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{external}

    \newcommand{\boxplot}[6]{%#max %no change
        %#1: center, #2: median, #3: 1/4 quartile, #4: 3/4 quartile, #5: min, #6: max
        \filldraw[fill=gray!25,line width=0.2mm] let \n{boxxl}={#1-0.4}, \n{boxxr}={#1+0.4} in (axis cs:\n{boxxl},#3) rectangle (axis cs:\n{boxxr},#4);
        % draw the box

        \draw[line width=0.2mm, color=orange] let \n{boxxl}={#1-0.1}, \n{boxxr}={#1+0.1} in (axis cs:\n{boxxl},#2) -- (axis cs:\n{boxxr},#2);
        % median
        \draw[line width=0.2mm,color=blue] (axis cs:#1,#4) -- (axis cs:#1,#6);
        % bar up
        \draw[line width=0.9mm,color=pink] let \n{whiskerl}={#1-0.025}, \n{whiskerr}={#1+0.025} in (axis cs:\n{whiskerl},#6) -- (axis cs:\n{whiskerr},#6);        % upper quartile
        \draw[line width=0.2mm,color=black] (axis cs:#1,#3) -- (axis cs:#1,#5);
        % bar down
        \draw[line width=0.6mm,color=yellow] let \n{whiskerl}={#1-0.025}, \n{whiskerr}={#1+0.025} in (axis cs:\n{whiskerl},#5) -- (axis cs:\n{whiskerr},#5);        % lower quartile
    }


    \begin{document}
    \tikzset{external/remake next}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            xmin=0.5, xmax=6, %x level interval
            ymin=1, ymax=100, % y level interval
                    xtick={1,2,3,4,5}, % X level name if not xtick level activate
                    xticklabels={Foo,20,Bar,SVM, DTree} % X level name
                 ]
    %#1: center, #2: median, #3: 1/4 quartile, #4: 3/4 quartile, #5: min, #6: max
    \boxplot{1}{8.5}{55}{69}{20}{35}
    \boxplot{2}{38.5}{55}{59}{40}{35}
    \boxplot{3}{8.5}{55}{29}{20}{35}
    \boxplot{4}{8.5}{55}{59}{20}{35}
    \boxplot{5}{8.5}{55}{89}{20}{35}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Image of the the code 
[image]

Comment: `pgfplots` can now do boxplots built-in, using the `statistics` library. But I am really not sure what you're after: the data you've provided don't make sense (min > max in boxplot 2 and median outside of [min,max] in all others).